# Is it possible to see the response of clicking a discord button before I do?

Tags: discord, discord-buttons

Let's say hypothetically I had a slash command in discord that prompted 10 buttons to show up each with a question mark on them. And when I clicked one it would be a random number between 1-10. Is there any way a person could potentially see what the number was prior to clicking said button?

I've tried using Google chromes "inspect" tool but had a hard time getting it to even see the code for the buttons. If it's random, is the button assigned prior to clicking it? Or can I figure out what the number is before clicking it?